# C++ Union of a Float and a Byte Array Issue

Tags: c++, avr, unions

I am working on an arduino (based off the AVR platform) and I have a method that takes in a float and writes it to EEPROM. I have to convert the float to a byte array to interact with EEPROM. I have two functions as follow:

```
void WriteFloatToEEPROM(int address, float value) {
    union {
        byte byteVal[4];
        float floatVal;
    } data;

    data.floatVal = value;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        EEPROM.update(address + i, data.byteVal[i]);
    }   
}

float ReadFloatFromEEPROM(int address) {
    union {
        byte byteVal[4];
        float floatVal;
    } data;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        uint8_t readValue = EEPROM.read(address + i);

        data.byteVal[i] = readValue;        
    }

    return data.floatVal;
}
```

When I print out the results of this I get the following as a few examples:

```
Read value at address 50 for float read 0
Read value at address 51 for float read 0
Read value at address 52 for float read 0
Read value at address 53 for float read 0
    Returned float val for address 50:0.00
Read value at address 90 for float read 0
Read value at address 91 for float read 0
Read value at address 92 for float read 0
Read value at address 93 for float read 160
    Returned float val for address 90:-0.00
Read value at address 130 for float read 44
Read value at address 131 for float read 113
Read value at address 132 for float read 61
Read value at address 133 for float read 138
    Returned float val for address 130:-0.00
Read value at address 170 for float read 0
Read value at address 171 for float read 0
Read value at address 172 for float read 0
Read value at address 173 for float read 0
    Returned float val for address 170:0.00
```

Am I using a union wrong/writing to EEPROM backwards or something? Also if anyone has a better way of doing this, I am open to suggestions. Thanks in advance

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11373203/accessing-inactive-union-member-and-undefined-behavior

Comment: Arduino programming is outside my expertise, but couldn't you just use [`EEPROM.put()`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/EEPROMPut) and [`EEPROM.get()`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/EEPROMGet)?

Comment: EEPROM.update is better to use because it only writes if the data is different at that location which saves a little bit of time (3.3ms) but also prevents writing to that location repeatedly which would burn up the EEPROM cell. Essentially it just does a get before the put as far as I've seen

Comment: Yes, but in the linked reference of `EEPROM.put()` I read: *"Note: This function **uses EEPROM.update()** to perform the write, so does not rewrites the value if it didn't change. "*. To my understanding is `EEPROM.write()` which doesn't check before writing.

Answer (score 7):

Reading not the "active" field of the union is UB (Undefined Behavior).

You have to use `memcpy`:

```
void WriteFloatToEEPROM(int address, float value) {
    byte byteVal[sizeof(float)];
    memcpy(byteVal, &value, sizeof(float));

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(float); i++) {
        EEPROM.update(address + i, byteVal[i]);
    }   
}

float ReadFloatFromEEPROM(int address) {
    byte byteVal[sizeof(float)];

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(float); i++) {
        byteVal[i] = EEPROM.read(address + i);
    }

    float f;
    memcpy(&f, byteVal, sizeof(float));
    return f;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this be a valid case for usage of `reinterpret_cast`?

Comment: @KillzoneKid probably works, but still has wiggles with strict aliasing.

Comment: @user4581301 `AliasedType is std::byte, (since C++17)char, or unsigned char: this permits examination of the object representation of any object as an array of bytes.` should be no problem then?

Comment: @KillzoneKid `float` to `char` array is safe, but the `char` array is not necessarily aligned correctly to be used as a `float`

Comment: @Jarod42 `for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)` should be `for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(float); ++i)` in both cases.

Comment: @KillzoneKid: the casting might only works with `float` to `const char*`. The other way would break strict aliasing.

Comment: @user4581301 Not sure I understand. Since we are copying bytes in a loop into EEPROM and back, under which circumstances we could have alignment problem? Using memcpy seems like doing the copying twice.

Comment: @KillzoneKid I think I know where you are going. You're saying we can safely cast `float *` to `char*`, so kill the intermediary buffer completely and read directly into the `float`. A loop around `float_as_charp[i] = read(i);`. I can't think of a good reason why that wouldn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Arduino provides [.put()](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/EEPROMPut) and [.get()](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/EEPROMGet) methods with `EEPROM` object so you don't have to reinvent the wheel. Your code could be as simple as:

```
void WriteFloatToEEPROM(int address, float value)
{
    EEPROM.put(address, value);
}

float ReadFloatFromEEPROM(int address)
{
    float value;
    EEPROM.get(address, value);
    return value;
}
```

`.put()` also acts in a similar way to `.update()`

> This function uses `EEPROM.update()` to perform the write, so does not
>   rewrites the value if it didn't change.

Comment: I will test this out on Monday, but I feel stupid for never finding the put/get methods. I've been using read/write/update the entire time. Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It is common problem for struct and union. You need investigate "aligns". Default it usually "word" (2 bytes) so your `byte byteVal[4];` can take 8 bytes (`byte, empty, byte, empty ...`). You must use `__attribute__ ((packed))` for avoid it.